# Install Powershell Script- Downloading from install url and saving to user machince

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

This is my first post so let me be upfront. Writing scripts IS SUPER new to me.
I use Ninja RMM to manage all of our clients machines. With in Ninja RMM you are able to write scripts using different languages. I choose PowerShell or Batch.

I wrote a script to install Anasa Desktop app silently for mass deployment. I tested the script on my machine and it seemed to work... I did get an error saying install failed because the program is already install. Therefore, I went to test the script on Ninja.  The process started but I never got notified if the script was successful or failed. Looking at the test machine this morning Asana is not installed. Any insight to this script would be welcomed. Thanks Community!

```
#installing Asana Desktop App
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\files' -Force
$folder = "c:\files"
$url= "https://desktop-downloads.asana.com/win32_x64/prod/latest/AsanaSetup.exe"
$req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Method = "HEAD"
$response = $req.GetResponse()
$fUri = $response.ResponseUri
$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fUri.LocalPath); 
$response.Close()
$target = join-path $folder $filename 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $target 



(Start-Process -FilePath $target -ArgumentList "/install /quiet /norestart" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the script but `AsanaSetup.exe --silent` installs it silently in user context and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Asana\Update.exe" --uninstall` will do "dirty" removal probably enough for it to be a working solution